# Troubles with JS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before I start, I'm going to point out that I am very, *very* new to JS and jQuery, so if this seems like a very simple fix to a very stupid problem, that is to be as expected.

I have a problem I want to solve using JS and jQuery where the script is used to insert content into a page.  Here's the part that the browser is getting caught up on in the console/debugger thing:

```
if(fname != "" && fname != null) {
    var newRow = 'A very long string whose contents are irrelevant here.'
    $( ".all-waiting" ).append( newRow );
}
```

The part it's getting hung up on specifically is the `$` in the jQuery statement which is supposed to be used to add the contents of the string to the specific page element.  I copied the format of the jQuery statement from a tutorial online and verified it against a version I had copied for a different project and managed to have work successfully.  What am I doing wrong here?  What should I be doing to append the string `newRow` to `.all-waiting`?

If it makes any difference, I'm introducing this script via an external JS page imported into an HTML page of my own creation.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: Here's the full relevant section of the JS code:

```
/*    ~~~~ Get's variables from URL ~~~~    */
// Syntax: getUrlVars()["variable"];
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}

var fname  = getUrlVars()["fname"];
var lname  = getUrlVars()["lname"];
var action = getUrlVars()["action"];
var other  = getUrlVars()["other"];



if(fname != "" && fname != null) {
    var newRow = '<tr><td class="time">00:00</td><td class="customer"><div class="cust-name">' + fname + ' ' + lname + '    </div><div class="cust-deets">Female, 40</div></td><td class="area none">' + action + '</td><td class="menu">___</td></tr>'
    $( ".all-waiting" ).append( newRow );
}
```

And the relevant HTML section:

```
<table class="all-waiting">
    <tr>
        <td class="time long">
            15:30
        </td>
        <td class="customer">
            <div class="cust-name">
                Samantha Wilson 
            </div>
            <div class="cust-deets">
                Female, 35
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="area">
            Foreign currency
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            ___
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="time">
            09:00
        </td>
        <td class="customer">
            <div class="cust-name">
                Ethan Blucher 
            </div>
            <div class="cust-deets">
                Male, 26
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="area">
            Business banking
        </td>
        <td class="menu">
            ___
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The script is supposed to add a new row to the table based on URL parameters.

Comment: did you include jQuery library to the page

Comment: In the head of the HTML page, I imported the following:
    `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: What do you mean by “getting hung up”? Do you get an _error_? If so, is it “`$` is not defined”?

Comment: You'd better also include your HTML code, as well as complete JS code. What I see here is that your JS code is not included within a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: are you getting any error in your browser console

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.html( newRow )` instead of `.append`? Since `newRow` is a text and not an element?

Comment: Can you post your html also?

Comment: @DigitalDouble http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c5xqnfzc/1/ ?

Comment: Its very trivial ...   `var newRow = $('A very long string whose contents are irrelevant here.')`

Comment: @JK. that won't work either because now you have created a selector

Comment: @Xufox: Yup, "$ is not defined"

Comment: @JK. That just causes an error on the `var newRow` line then because of the $

Comment: @Imamadmad if $ is not defined then you're not including jQuery correctly.  According to your comment above, it seems that wherever your page (html file) lives, you have your external script named `script.js` as well, and then have a subfolder called `js` that has `jquery.js` in it. Is that correct?

Comment: @DigitalDouble Nope, doesn't work

Comment: @EricLease No, I don't have a subfolder with a jQuery file in it.  That's just what one webpage told me to add to import jQuery.  It never mentioned anything about having to save a separate jQuery file.

Comment: @Imamadmad So you don’t have a local `jquery.js` file? How do you expect the browser to find this file then?

Comment: @Imamadmad are you referencing a jQuery CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're not referencing or loading jQuery before your script.

First try replacing

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

with...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If that does not work then it is an issue of jQuery not yet being loaded when you attempt to used it.  If that is the case, I will change my answer, but I doubt it is.  Chances are replacing that line will work, and we know the code in question works when jQuery is loaded (as evidenced by Arun's fiddle).  So if that works then it's just a matter of getting the correct path for your `<script>` tag's `src` attribute.

According to your comments you have a file structure like...

```
~/page.html
~/script.js
~/js/jquery.js
```

So make sure you actually have the jQuery source saved as `jquery.js` in a subfolder `js` under the folder that your HTML file is in - or find/download it and/or update the path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I knew it was going to be something simple that I missed!  That'll teach me to Google functions before doing a proper tutorial from the start!

Comment: @Imamadmad If you "fixed" this by just replacing your line with mine then please try to understand why that solves the problem.  You need this external resource (jQuery), and you don't have it on your webserver's local file system (local path is indicated by relative path - a path starting with `/`, `./`, or `../`), so the line I gave you is actually going and downloading a copy of that file from a remote repository.  This is a very standard thing nowadays, but you should understand that you're relying on a 3rd party to provide you the source *at runtime*.